# Axiom about the maximum number of vectors of alternating orientation around a point.

Tags: geometry

This is not a question of independent vectors in a Cartesian coordinate system. It results from a question in physics [about the number of bar magnets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/548786/46708) around a point in 3D with changing orientation of their poles to the center.

Boundary conditions:

1. The vectors are all of equal length and the sum of the vectors must be zero.
2. All direct neighboring vectors should have a changing orientation. Direct neighbours are those with the shortest distance between the outer ends of the vectors. ((The next vectors further away all should be again at the same distance from and pointing in the same direction as the central vector. I think this is more of a remark because it follows from point 1).

2.1. Imagine, that the vectors represent bar magnets and - within an ideal position of them - they get attracted in all direction with equal force. Means, all neighbors with the same distance will not attract nor repeal any vector. So inverting a copy of the 8 vectors and rotating them a bit is not a solution. All the two vectors pairs  (bar magnets) will stick together at once.

3. The solution I ask for is only needed for 3D, the 2D solution is, as mentioned in the comments, "any even number of vectors with changing orientations and equal distances in a planar circular arrangement". For higher dimensions I do not need a solution (it’s out of my interest).
4. All vectors should point to or from the common center. A layer-wise solution is not requested.
5. Are there solutions to narrow down the possible solutions that are multiples of the 8 vectors? Perhaps imagine a next shell around the last 8 vectors that continues their symmetry. Or put the new vectors in between the existing 8. $^1$$^)$

For illustration I draw it. For better visualization of the positions of the vectors the cube was drawn in.

[image]

Explanation for the neighbors shortest distance: As you can see in the sketch for every vectors on a cube, the three neighbors of a vector are those, located at the end of the three edges starting from this vertex.

My intuition tells me that there are *maximum and only* 8 vectors (and they are located on the edges of a cube). Can this be proven?

$^1$$^)$ After having Alex Ravsky’s answer it turns out, that point 5 is a main point. Thanks also for the discussion in the comments that helps me to understand the needed conditions.

Comment: It would also be helpful to include the complete explicit list of conditions on the vectors (there seem to be some additional tacit ones); since if we assume just the two listed in this question, we could simply place any even number of vectors with alternating orientations and equal spacing in a planar circular arrangement.

Comment: I don't see why the solution from 2D wouldn't be applicable in this case, embedded on the xy-plane? Maybe one could even take a second copy of it with changed orientations and put them one over another, i.e. obtaining a prisma over a regular 2n-gon. Wouldn't these be valid solutions, as they both follow your conditions?

Comment: Unless some requirements are missing I'm fairly sure I can construct a set of 48 such vectors. The cube has 48 symmetries, and the group $G$ is generated by orthogonal reflection w.r.t. three carefully chosen planes through the origin. We pick a vector $x$ that has the same distance to all the three planes. It is then easy to see that within the orbit $G\cdot x$ the closest points are always "one reflection away from each other". Meaning that each vector has three closest neighbors.

Comment: (cont'd) The group $G$ has an index two subgroup $H$ of orientation preserving symmetries. If we orient the vectors in the orbit $H\cdot x$ pointing out, and the complementary half pointing out, then it follows that the closest neighbors will always have opposite orientation, because a reflection reverses handedness.

Comment: Actually, using the same idea we should be able to use icosahedral symmetries to generate a set of 120 such vectors. See [this WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry). Look at the image with the 120 spherical triangles, alternatingly colored black and white. Imagine an outpointing vector through each black triangle, and an in-pointing vector through each white triangle. That explains what you can expect from this idea. And possibly allow you to formulate a missing condition if any.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Nice. What is the minimum possible number greater 8? What the solution with multiples of 8? You are the closest to my conditions because you focused on equal rectangles which is a symmetric solution. For better imagination think about bar magnets which should be in perfect equilibration. The equal rectangles (or n-tangles?) are needed for this, that's what I think.

Comment: The condition 2.1. changes the scene. I want to ask one thing: are you sure that your set of 8 vectors have that kind of an equilibrium? Rotational symmetry of order three around any vector leaves the possibility that each magnet experiences a radial net force, pushing it further out or drawing it straight in. It seems possible to me that the three closest neighbors generate a strong attraction that is not offset by the repulsion of the more distant triplet. And we haven't even accounted for the attraction of the opposite magnet.

Comment: It is possible that I misunderstand the physics. My thinking may apply only to point charges of opposing signs at the end points of the vectors. Also, I didn't check the magnitudes of the various radial components, so may be they do cancel?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It is enough to think in vectors. The orders of magnitude are all the same (point 1). Maybe the question is not well prepared, especially the point that the 8 existing vectors are part of the next level we are looking for. Perhaps I should sort myself and ask a renewed question? Because the answers are right as long as I do not restrict more and more  the conditions. I’m not happy with this because later readers are not able to  understand the answers in the context of the changed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as an answer, because I still want more feedback from the OP. And I need to post pictures to get that so it has to be an answer.

---

My idea is to use orbits of a Coxeter group. So if $G$ is a finite group generated by orthogonal reflections through the origin, and $x\in\Bbb{R}^3$ a carefully chosen "initial point", then the set of vectors

$$C=\{g(x)\mid g\in G\}$$

will have some nice properties that I describe below:

1. In 3D we can use three planes, $H_1,H_2,H_3$, (= the walls of a Weyl chamber) such that $G$ is then generated by the reflections $s_i, i=1,2,3,$ w.r.t. these walls.
2. Without loss of generality we can assume that $x$ is within that Weyl chamber (examples below). When that happens it is easy prove that the minimum distance between two points of $C$ is equal to the distance between $x$ and the closest of the points $s_i(x),i=1,2,3$. This is obvious to anyone well versed in Coxeter groups.
3. So if we select $x$ so that it is equidistant from all the three walls, then we know that $x$ has three closest neighbors $s_i(x), i=1,2,3$.
4. The elements of $G$ are all distance preserving (i.e. elements of $O(3)$). Therefore the conclusion of the previous bullet applies more generally. Every element of $C$ has three equidistant closest neighbors. The closest neighbors of $g(x)$ are $g(s_i(x)), i=1,2,3$.
5. The generators $s_1,s_2,s_3$ are all reflection w.r.t a plane, so they reverse handedness (have determinants $=-1$). It follows that $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index two consisting of the elements of $G\cap SO(3)$. Observe that none of the generators $s_i$ are in $H$. This is important.
6. We then split $C$ into two parts:
   $$C_+=\{g(x)\mid g\in H\}\qquad\text{and}\qquad C_-=\{g(x)\mid g\notin H\}.$$ Observe that the closest neighbors of any vector $y\in C$ belong to the opposite half. Therefore we get a desirable construction by drawing the vectors related to $C_+$ pointing out, and those related to $C_-$ pointing in.
7. Because $C$ is a single orbit of a subgroup of $O(3)$ the resulting collection is *homogeneous*. Meaning that by rotating the space in an appropriate way we can bring any vector to the position of $x$ in such a way that the entire constellation $C$ is rotated back to itself $-$ the constellation looks alike around any one of its points.

---

As an example let us consider the Coxeter group of symmetries of a cube. These are orthogonal transformations of the form 
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto (\pm x_{\sigma(1)},\pm x_{\sigma(2)},\pm x_{\sigma(3)})$$
with all $8$ sign combos and all $6$ permutations $\sigma\in S_3$ for a total of $48$ elements in $G$. This turns out to be a Coxeter group (take my word for it for now) generated by the reflections

- $s_1(x,y,z)=(y,x,z)$, the reflection w.r.t. the plane $H_1:x=y$,
- $s_2(x,y,z)=(x,z,y)$, the reflection w.r.t. the plane $H_2:y=z$,
- $s_3(x,y,z)=(x,y,-z)$, the reflection w.r.t. the plane $H_3:z=0$.

The (fundamental) Weyl chamber then consists of the points with coordinates $(x,y,z)$
satisfying $x\ge y\ge z\ge0$. The point $x=(1+2\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2,1)$ is then at distance
$1$ from all the planes $H_i$. It may be easier to verify that $d(s_i(x),x)=2$ for all $i=1,2,3$. Anyway, the resulting picture looks like the following:

[image]

The vectors in $C_+$ are red and those in $C_-$ are blue. I could reverse the direction of the blue arrows, but then the blue arrowheads would form an uninformative lump at the origin. I'm afraid the picture may not be very intuitive.

Below there is another image of the same configuration. This time I added the three walls $H_1,H_2,H_3$. The fundamental Weyl chamber is the pyramid shape in the front. You see the red vector $x$ inside it, its arrowhead equidistant from the three walls.

[image]

If $g\in G$ and $H$ is a wall of the chamber around $x$, then $g(H)$ is a wall of the chamber containing $g(x)$.
In the next picture we see all the $48$ chambers. Alltogether there are nine planes of reflective symmetry, and these are the walls separating the chambers. I tried to pick the view point in such a way that you see an octant split into six chambers in the front. Each chamber within an octant has the absolute values of the coordinates are sorted in one of the six possible specific ordes.

[image]

The homogeneity of the constellation manifests itself in several ways. All the chambers have the same shape, each has three walls, each contains one vector, red or blue, according to the rule that every time you cross a wall to the adjacente chamber the color changes.

---

A smaller example of $24$ vectors can be gotten by using the group of $24$ symmetries of a regular tetrahedron. Imagine that the four vertices of a tetrahedron are at the points $(\pm a,\pm a,\pm a)$ where we this time only allow an even number of minus signs (so two or none). The corresponding Coxeter group is a subgroup of the previous group of transformations, where this time we only allow an even number of sign changes. The generators $s_1$ and $s_2$ from above can be reused, but I replace $s_3$ with
$$
s_3':(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,-z,-y)
$$
reflecting w.r.t. the plane $H_3':y=-z$. This time there are only six walls altogether (because reflections w.r.t. the coordinate planes are no longer symmetries). We readily see that the initial vector $x=(2,1,0)$ is at distance
$\sqrt2/2$ from all the walls $H_1,H_2,H_3'$.
The picture with chamber, walls and blue/red arrows looks like the following.

[image]

The remark about the color changing every time we cross the wall from one chamber to an adjacent one applies. This time we have four chambers on each face of the cube.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler The space is split into $48$ chambers, each with three walls. The second picture shows the walls discussed in the answer. The "initial vector" is the only vector inside that chamber. Those three reflections generate a group of $48$.

Comment: Could you use the octahedron as walls? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid#/media/File:Dual_Cube-Octahedron.svg Why? Because of my annoying restriction of 8 vectors.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Working on a constellation of $24$...

Comment: @HolgerFiedler The octahedron and the cube share the same group of symmetries, and would thus give rise to the same constellation.

Comment: Thinking about the stability condition 2.1. The symmetry should help there.

Comment: Very intuitiv. Thank you for doing so much work. I’ll tell you the whole story. Based on two vectors (bar magnets), the next shell consists 8 magnets in equilibration with the 2 in the inner shell. Without this constellation, I’ve learned from your images, that countless solutions are possible. And still I believe (a very bad word in science) that around the 8 vectors no more solutions are possible. But if, it would be great.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I'm not sure about these constellation being physically stable. With the magnets there may be some higher order dipole-like things that are non-zero. With the smaller constellation of 24 the symmetries dictate that the net force on any magnet is along the coordinate plane that point happens to lie on. But in that configuration each magnet would only lie on a single such plane of symmetry. If I use a non-trivial stabilizer, that may help. But the constellation is then much smaller. I may need to go to the icosahedral group to get large stabilizers, but I'm not sure it helps.

Comment: Too late an hour for me to calculate net forces. If you have a tool for quickly checking the stability, the points in the latter configuration have coordinates $(2,1,0)$ in any of the six orders and any of the four possible sign combinations.

Comment: Anyway, a problem with using Coxeter groups is that there are darn few of them in any given dimension. The condition that a finite group should be generated by reflections w.r.t. a hyperplane is VERY strong, and ties our hands.

Comment: To make an earlier point clearer. I suspect that in your configuration of 8 magnets you have all the 48 symmetries of the cube (or 24 when taking the orientation changes into account). So a stabilizer of order six (or three). And that stabilier subgroup then imposes its symmetries on the net force. By using a bigger orbit of the same group Ii get more vectors, but I lose that stabilizer. And therefore some of the symmetries of the net force. That may spell doom.

Comment: Reading here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid#Combinatorial_properties, I see that the 8 vertices of the cube and the corresponding 8 faces of the octahedron are the only geometrical elements with the number 8. What degenerations are there with geometric elements with multiples of 8? Not sure if that helps. Anyway, it is posted :-)

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of configurations of vectors satisfying the conditions. We can construct them as follows. Pick any finite set $V$ of vectors of unit length with zero sum. Let $V’$ be a set consisting of vectors $V$ simultaneously rotated by a sufficiently small angle around the origin $O$ and with altered directions. Then each vector $v$ has as the closest neighbor its redirected and rotated copy and vice versa, and the sum of all vectors in $V\cup V'$ is zero.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler It seems that even with this restriction we still have a lot of freedom, becuse we can take unions of configurations provided they do not “interfere”, that is the pairs of the closest neighbors remains in the union. This holds if the smallest angle between rays of vectors of different sets of the unioin is bigger that the largest angle between  closest neighbors in each set of the union.

Comment: Now, if $V$ is the configuration consisting of the eight given vectors, for each $\varepsilon>0$ we can construct a configuration $V’$ similarly to described above such that each vector $v$ in $V$ has a closest neighbor $v’\in V’$ which is $\varepsilon$-close (and vice versa). Now we can take unions of $V\cup V’$ with many configurations from the answer.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler To restrict configuration freedom we can impose some symmetrical conditions on a configuration $V$. For instance, we can require the transitivity: for each two vectors $v$ and $v’$ of $V$ with the same orientation (towards or from the origin) there exists a symmetry of $V$ which transforms $v$ to $v’$.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I fixed this issue in my second solution, providing for each vector $v$ of the eight vectors a new and unique $\varepsilon$-close closest neighbor $v$, so we don’t need to care about the vectors of the added configurations, because they are placed more far from $v$ than $v’$.

Comment: One more idea: we can try to construct other symmetrical configuration placing the endpoints of the vectors at the vertices of  [Archimedean solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_solid).

Comment: @HolgerFiedler It suffices to add to the set $V$ of the initial eight vectors its alternated and rotated copy $V'$, so there are $16$ vectors in total.

Comment: Seems to me impossible. You get two closest vectors of the same direction. Point 2 is not fulfilled? (I delete comments not to run into chat room, that is very fast the end of any discussion in my experiences with xSE :-)

Comment: @HolgerFiedler No, the closest vectors have opposite orientations. To obtain $V’$  from $V$ we first alternate the direction of each vector of $V$ and then rotate them.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Alex's suggestion was to rotate the second copy of the vectors (those with flipped orientation) just a _tiny tiny_ little bit, so that the original closest neighbours cease to be the closest and each vector (both old and new one) will have just one closest neighbour -- its inverted-and-slightly-rotated clone. For your picture, imagine rotating the cloned vectors by, say, one degree.

Comment: @PeterKošinár Get it. This is elegant and ingeniously simple but not a solution because the new vectors should work with the same conditions and they do not, their neighbors are of different distance. I see, that my question is not well prepaired but anyway very useful for me. I’ll add some sentences in the question again. Hope, nobody is angry.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Indeed, it is one of the problems where it is quite difficult to capture all the intuitive expectations on the desired configuration explicitly. I'll provide another construction which places unbounded number of vectors while satisfying additional restrictions; this might help with formulating the specific conditions to rule out such configuration (if they are undesirable).

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be a positive integer. I'll describe placement of $4n$ unit vectors pointing to or from the common origin using geography-like coordinate system with longitude between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$ and latitude between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$.

Let $\alpha=360^\circ/(2n)$. For $k$ between $0$ and $(2n-1)$, place one vector at

- longitude $k\alpha$ and latitude $+\alpha/2$, pointing inwards if and only if $k$ is even.
- longitude $k\alpha$ and latitude $-\alpha/2$, pointing inwards if and only if $k$ is odd.

Note that for $n=2$, this construction produces the cube-based configuration described in the question.

For general $n$, the configuration has the following properties:

- The vectors lie on circles in two parallel planes, thus satisfying condition (3).
- The sum of vectors from each plane is zero, so the full configuration clearly satisfies condition (1).
- They all point from/to the common origin; satisfying condition (4).
- Each vector has three closest neighbours at angle $\alpha$; two at the same latitude to the east and west, and one at the same longitude but sign-flipped latitude across the equator. This satisfies the main condition (2) to some extent, subject to interpretation of the part in parentheses.
- If we choose any two vectors of the same inward/outward orientation, we can rotate the configuration to make one match the other; which means they satisfy the *transitivity* requirement suggested by **Alex Ravsky** in a comment.

Yet, it is likely that even this configuration is not a desirable one since it does not seem to satisfy the *physical stability* condition (2.1). Perhaps this one is the one which captures the intended properties the best? At the same time, that condition is a global one (rather than the "closest neighbours" one which can be checked locally).

Comment: Sorry about forgetting to upvote this right away. I was busy with my own pictures. Yes, this gives what I called a "homogeneous" constellation (transitive group of symmetries). The comment I really wanted to make is that you can slightly modify this idea as follows. Rotate the southern latitude by an angle $\alpha/2$, and adjust the latitudes to $\pm\beta$ with $\beta$ slightly less than $\alpha$. That way each point will have four nearest neighbors: two on the same latitude, and two on the opposite one (the longitudes interlace nicely). The formula for $\beta$ is complicated.

Comment: (cont'd) The point was that because $\beta$ is slightly less than $\alpha$, the latitudes become longer, and the minimum distance between two points increases a little. This is not important here, but becomes so for closely related problems, where maximizing the minimum distance is important :-)